# Extending a script to loop over multiple files and generate output names

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have following script (named vid2gif.sh) to convert a video file to gif:

```
#! /bin/bash
ffmpeg -i $1 /tmp/gif/out%04d.gif
gifsicle --delay=10 --loop /tmp/gif/*.gif > $2
```

I can convert a file using command:

```
vid2gif.sh myvid.mp4 myvid.gif
```

How can I make it to convert all mp4 files in a folder? That is, how can I make following command work:

```
vid2gif.sh *.mp4
```

The script should output files as *.gif. Thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI, using `.sh` extensions for executable scripts (as opposed to shell libraries intended to be invoked with `source`) is bad form -- executable scripts define commands, and UNIX commands don't have extensions -- they're inherently language-agnostic, as the shebang line at the top defines how they're interpreted. See http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful.shtml for a longer discussion.

Comment: (Also, scripts starting with `#!/bin/bash` are bash scripts, not POSIX sh scripts, so using `.sh` extensions for them is misleading; many such scripts will break in surprising ways if run with `sh somescript`, which the extension implies is supported).

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. So I should save this script as vid2gif, move it to /usr/local/bin folder and run it as 'vid2gif'. Is that right?

Comment: ...and use `chmod +x` to mark it executable, yes. If you didn't want to install it for all users, but only for yourself, you might consider making a `$HOME/bin` directory and adding that to your `PATH`.

Comment: The way the title is now written -- looping over files, rather than arguments -- is a little more general, so I've modified section (1) of my answer to suit.

Comment: Many thanks for your clear answer with detailed explanation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : I added the script to $HOME/bin and added that to the path. But then many things went wrong and I need sudo also to have that path and that too before rc.local is read & executed. How can I do that?

Comment: If this is something you want to run from `rc.local`, `/usr/local/bin` is a better location. As for having a script that will automatically sudo itself when need be -- that can be done, but it's probably better asked as a separate question (if not already asked and answered elsewhere here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
for f; do
  tempdir=$(mktemp -t -d gifdir.XXXXXX)
  ffmpeg -i "$f" "$tempdir/out%04d.gif"
  gifsicle --delay=10 --loop "$tempdir"/*.gif >"${f%.*}.gif"
  rm -rf "$tempdir"
done
```

Let's go over how this works:

1. Iteration

   ```
   for f; do
   ```

   is equivalent to `for f in "$@"`; that is to say, it loops over all command-line arguments. If instead you wanted to loop over all MP4s in the current directory, this would be `for f in *.mp4; do`, or to loop over all MP4s named in the directory passed as the first command line argument, it would be `for f in "$1"/*.mp4; do`. To support either usage -- but go with the first one if no directory is passed -- it would be `for f in "${1:-.}"/*.mp4; do`.
2. Temporary directory use

   Because the original script would reuse `/tmp/gif` for everything, you'd get files from one input source being used in others. This is best avoided by creating a new temporary directory for each input file, which `mktemp` will automate.
3. Creating the `.gif` name

   `"${f%.*}"` is a parameter expansion which removes everything after the last `.` in a file; see [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) for documentation on string manipulation in bash in general, including this particular form.

   Thus, `"${f%.*}.gif"` strips the existing extension, and adds a `.gif` extension.

Comment: Typically in the location defined by the environment variable `TEMPDIR`, or `/tmp` if unset. See `man mktemp` on your system for precise docs.